# Having monitoring data of multiple counters in a period of time and an array of counters how correlations with counters of intrest?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, statistics, monitoring, libraries

So we have a `Dictionary` of counter names with `Lists` of counters data. We have a `List` of counter names we are interested in. We want to find counter names that can be related to our selected counters (say have similar behaviour in all peaks or at least similar at some). On a picture Black curve is related to red and marron but not to blue:

[image]

So having monitoring data of multiple (say 20000) counters in a period of time and an array of counters of intrest how to find counters that correlate to ones of intrest? Is there any opensource (or native to framework) .net library for such correlation analysis?

Answer (score 0):

There's [Math.NET](http://www.mathdotnet.com/) which supports numerical analysis and signal processing. Personally I haven't worked with it but if it supports signal processing I'm sure there is some way to calculate the correlation or covariance or signals or data.